# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Hello  guys :) I have to write a little calculator (DEX>BIN) and im stuck with one little problem that i cant solve. The problem:
When i send a blank form it says:
**ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''**
but when i send something in the form it does work. Can someone help me ?

```
 if check_login():
            data = 0
            if request.method == 'POST':
                if request.form['table'] != None:

                    if request.form['dextobin']!= '0':                   
                        data = request.form['table']
                        data = int(data) 
                        data = bin(data)[2:]
                        data = str(data)
                    elif request.form['bintodex'] != '0':
                        data = 111
                    else:
                        data = 11
            return render_template('kalkulator.html', wynik = data)
        else:
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

SOLVE:

```
   if request.method == 'POST':
        data=''
        if request.form.get('table'):
            if  not request.form.get('dextobin'):
                data = request.form.get('table')
                data = int(data) 
                data = bin(data)[2:]
                data = str(data)            
        else:
            data='Where is your integers ! ?'
    return render_template('kalkulator.html', wynik = data)
else:
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

Comment: Check for empty string and set result to 0? Or whatever is applicable.

Comment: Hah, i just changed  if request.form['table'] != None to  if request.form['table']  and it does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `data = request.form.get('table', 0)` instead

Comment: What 0 does ? Thanks for your help mate !

Comment: 0 is the default value when request.form['table'] is None